# DataContext LINQ Queries - Should I use my own data object classes?

Tags: performance, linq, viewmodel, datacontext

I apologize if my vocabulary is off on the following question.

I have an SQL Database that has multiple relationships to tables within that database.  I've created a DataContext for this database and create a repository of functions used to call it's data.

My question is, because of the relationships (Multiple Linked tables).

Should I create my own class object to hold the results and only grab the needed table's column data  like the following:

```
   public IQueryable<VM_userLogs> getUserLogsVM(Nullable<DateTime> startDate, Nullable<DateTime> endDate)
{
    if (startDate == null) {
        startDate = Convert.ToDateTime("01-01-1900");
    }

    if (endDate == null) {
        endDate = Convert.ToDateTime("01-01-2900");
    }

    IQueryable<VM_userLogs> logs = from l in ctx.tools_trt_userLogs 
                   where l.timeStamp >= startDate & l.timeStamp <= endDate 
                   select new VM_userLogs {
                            LOG_ID = l.logId,
                            NTLOGIN = l.ntLogin,
                            PRODUCT = l.productName,
                            SEGMENT = l.segmentName,
                            PRIORITY = l.priority,
                            GROUP = l.groupName,
                            ANSWER = l.answerText,
                            TIMESTAMP = l.timeStamp,
                            URL = l.url
                        };
    return logs;
}
```

or can I just call the underlying object from the datacontext and NOT take a big performance hit... Like the following:

```
    public IQueryable<tools_trt_userLogs> getUserLogs(Nullable<DateTime> startDate, Nullable<DateTime> endDate)
{
    if (startDate == null)
    {
        startDate = Convert.ToDateTime("01-01-1900");
    }

    if (endDate == null)
    {
        endDate = Convert.ToDateTime("01-01-2900");
    }

    IQueryable<tools_trt_userLogs> logs = from l in ctx.tools_trt_userLogs
                                   where l.timeStamp >= startDate & l.timeStamp <= endDate
                                   select l;
    return logs;
}
```

Comment: Do you use lazy loading?

Comment: Yes.  I do not use/load the object until it is needed.

Comment: Then there shouldn't be much of a difference.